# FluentValidation is not displaying error for IEnumerable

Tags: c#, validation

I have a model class like below.

```
public class EditJob
{
   ...
    public JobPost JobPost { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<JobRequirement> JobRequirement { get; set; }
}
```

and my fluentvalidation class.

```
 public class EmployeeEditJobValidation:AbstractValidator<EditJob>
    {
       public EmployeeEditJobValidation()
        {
         RuleFor(edit => edit.JobPost.Experience).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Experience cannot be empty").GreaterThan(-1).WithMessage("Please add experience");
         RuleFor(edit => edit.JobPost.Industry).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please select Industry");
                  ......
                  .....
          RuleForEach(edit => edit.JobRequirement).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Requirement cannot be empty.");

         }
   }
```

The noticed the Ienumerable type controls are not validating. I modified my EmployeeEditJobValidation for the IEnumrale to

```
RuleForEach(edit => edit.JobRequirement).Must((e, f) => notEmpty(e.JobRequirement)).WithMessage("Requirement is required").NotEmpty().WithMessage("Requirement cannot be empty.");
```

and

```
 private bool notEmpty(IEnumerable<JobRequirement> re)
 {
            return re.All(x => x.Requirement != null);

 }
```

Now when i run its validating. However, the error messages are not displaying beneath the controls as required. Below is my view

```
@foreach(var item in Model.JobRequirement)
  {

      @Html.EditorFor(m => item)
  }
```

and an editorTemplate

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("JobRequirement")) 
{    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group"> 
          <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
             <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>

          </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
          ......
          .......

           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Requirement,new { @class = "form-control" })
             <span class="text-danger">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Requirement)</span>
         </div>

    </div>
   </div> 
   <br />

}
```

Please how do i get this working ? were do i go wrong ? Any help suggestion or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Nuru, did you ever figure this out?